# Show that if $Q_1,Q_2,...$ is a countable collection of rectangles covering $Q$,then $v(Q)\leq\sum v(Q_i).$

Tags: real-analysis

- Show that if $Q_1,Q_2,...$ is a countable collection of rectangles covering $Q$,then $v(Q)\leq\sum v(Q_i).$

If the collection $Q_i$ is finite, then pick the rectangle $Q'$ that covers all of $Q,Q_1,Q_2,\ldots,Q_n$, and partition it using the endpoints of $Q,Q_1,Q_2,\ldots,Q_n$ in each axis. Then each subrectangle of $Q$ determined by this partition is also a subrectangle of one of the $Q_i$'s, and the result follows.

When the collection $Q_i$ is countable and infinite, how can we prove, may you help?

NOTE: $v$ means 'volume'.

Comment: What does $v$ stand for?

Comment: @Gae.S. volume.